# Opening a new GUI from a message returned from server Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am designing a project for a class that opens a series of GUI's before reaching the GUI. each component functions independently but when we try and use a message returned from a server to create a new GUI, it makes the window, but with none of the components. any ideas?

for example.

we have a log in screen come up, which then sends the ID to the server, which returns a list of available whiteboards to the client, this works fine. then when we want the client to create a GUI after the message received it comes up with a box that is titled correctly but none of the components are there. i had this working earlier skipping the available boards and just opening a whiteboard, none of the components of the whiteboard were created although, the computer thought it had created a whiteboard successfully.

we tried something like this...

```
ChooseBoardGUI newChoose = new ChooseBoardGUI(out, availableBoards);
newChoose.setVisible(true);
newChoose.pack();
String numberOfBoard = in.readLine().substring(2);
WhiteboardGUI a = createWhiteboard(out, numberOfBoard);
```

any ideas on why the new GUI would come up blank?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Possible problems:

- You're calling a long-running task on the Swing event thread, tying it up so that it can't paint the GUI as it is supposed to do. Perhaps you're waiting on a socket to send information in but doing this within the EDT, or Swing **E**vent **D**ispatch **T**hread. This is a common cause of a window being created but not being properly painted.
- Or you've got a bug in code not shown (well this is undoubtedly true since you're not showing us any relevant code, and so I should re-phrase it, "you've got a bug in code not shown, other than described in the preceding bullet").

The solution is:

- If your problem is due to the first issue, then be sure to have all long-running tasks run in a thread background to the Swing event thread. A SwingWorker can work well for this.
- If your problem is the second issue, well then show us more code and give more information. Preferably create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check out the link).

As an aside: it sounds as if your GUI is structured to throw several JFrames at the user. If so, consider re-designing your code so that your separate GUI's are geared towards creating JPanels, and then have your program show one main stable JFrame but swaps "*views*", again usually JPanels, via a CardLayout.

---

A great tutorial on Swing Concurrency: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. I am waiting for a message to be returned from a server through a socket. Is it possible to use the wait() function till the message is received till we create the GUI. Is that what is taking so long? If the wait method does solve it, how would we best use it?

Comment: @CreedJarrettMangrum: as mentioned above, all waiting absolutely needs to be done on a background thread. As mentioned, consider using a SwingWorker for this. Google the tutorial on the SwingWorker as it's quite good. Again, if you need more help, you're going to have to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). The code you've posted is completely unrelated to your current problem and does not help us.

Comment: @CreedJarrettMangrum: I've added a link to the Swing concurrency tutorial to the bottom of my answer.